# Windows error code is 0 after exiting with error in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, windows, exit

I'm testing an application that runs on both MacOS and Windows using Node.

If I have a program that exits with an error, the exit code is set on MacOS but not Windows. Running the error command $((0/0)) in PowerShell and I find no $LASTEXITCODE or $? is populated. I get $LASTEXITCODE=0 and $?=True. Does Windows just swallow exit codes unless explicitly set in the code? In Terminal on MacOS, the exit code gets set to 1.

Is there a different exit code I should be looking for instead on Windows?

Here's a code sample of a test that triggers this behavior:

```
describe("runSubprocess", () => {
  it("returns non-zero when subprocess fails", async () => {
    const exitCode = await runSubprocess("echo", ["$((0/0))"]);
    expect(exitCode).not.toEqual(0);
  });
});

function runSubProcess(command: string, args: ReadonlyArray<string>) {
  process.stdout.write("> " + command + " " + args.join(" ") + "\n");
  const childProcess = spawn(command, args, {
    stdio: ["inherit", "pipe", "pipe"],
    shell: true,
  });
  return new Promise((resolveFunc) => {
    childProcess.stdout.on("data", (x) => {
      process.stdout.write(x.toString());
    });
    childProcess.stderr.on("data", (x) => {
      process.stderr.write(x.toString());
    });
    childProcess.on("exit", (code) => {
      resolveFunc(code);
    });
  });
}
```

Tried running this test on MacOS and Windows. It works as expected on MacOS.

I've also tried running the command in PowerShell and Terminal. The same behavior occurs.

Comment: in Windows try to check %errorlevel% after exiting the program. Maybe that helps